# How set default Kernal boot in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, kernel

I want to default boot an older Kernal of Ubuntu, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: which Ubuntu version?  `grub2` config is a little different than `grub`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit menu.lst in /boot/grub/
And set the 'default 0' to the number of the entry you want

Comment: This was the fix, thank you for the help mgb!

Answer (score 3):

You can select the default kernel by editing `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and changing

```
default 0
```

to the index of the kernel you want on the list, e.g. `default 3` would load the fourth kernel.

If you want to be more dynamical, you can save the latest selection as the default by changing the line above to say `default saved` and enable the savedefault setting in the automagic kernel list by changing `# savedefault=false` to `# savedefault=true`. Remember not to uncomment the line! This change needs to be activated by running `sudo update-grub`.

After that, whichever kernel you choose to boot, will be the default selection next time.